# Django models vs raw SQL queries

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on my senior design project, and I've got some questions about Django that I'm having trouble finding the answers to. If these questions have been answered before, please just point me in the right direction because my searches weren't turning up anything.

The general scope of the project is a website that interfaces with a database. I'm personally responsible for developing the DB as well as writing some API to make it easier on my team, who is less familiar with SQL base languages.

I've already built a prototype of my database in mysql, but I later found out that Django's implementation of database integration uses models, and it looks it ultimately replaces the mysql implementation. Since I've already built the database, should I redesign it with Django or am I safe to continue only using raw queries? Are there any significant security concerns to be aware of if I decide to forgo the model method of implementation?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: you should probably use the ORM (django models) provided ... rather than your own solution ... that said you certainly can run your own queries ...

Comment: the Django ORM is pretty nice, it makes lots of common tasks much easier.  I tend to revert to SQL for big analytics type work, but mostly it's **much** more convenient to work with the ORM